# How to export from org-mode to LaTeX ~⟨code snippet⟩~ into \lstinline[...]+⟨code snippet⟩+ (just as src_⟨language⟩{⟨code snippet⟩})?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

With `(setq org-latex-listings t)`, `src_⟨language⟩{⟨code snippet⟩}` is exported from `org-mode` to `LaTeX` into `\lstinline[language=⟨language⟩]~⟨code snippet⟩~` (here, `~` could be almost any token): so far, so good.

Is there a way to obtain the same export with the usual `org-mode` syntax for code snippets: `~⟨code snippet⟩~` (this supposes the `⟨language⟩` to be declared globally)?

```
#+OPTIONS:   toc:nil title:nil

#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{xcolor}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{listings}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \lstset{language=[auto]lisp,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\color{red}}

#+PROPERTY: header-args :padline no :exports both :noweb yes :eval always

src_lisp{defun} is fun!

~defun~ is fun!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transcoding of `~foo~` is done by `org-latex-code`, so you can redefine this function:

```el
(defun org-latex-code (code _contents info)
  "Transcode a CODE object from Org to LaTeX.
CONTENTS is nil.  INFO is a plist used as a communication
channel."
  (format "\\lstinline[language=%s]~%s~"
          my-default-code-markup-language
          (org-element-property :value code)))

(setq my-default-code-markup-language "Lisp")
```

You have to make sure that the redefinition of the function is done *after* `ox-latex` is loaded. `with-eval-after-load` might be useful for that.